# Skip a row, start sum process again

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report generated from a program that opens in excel similar to the image below

[image: spreadsheet]

I have been using this code to sum the amounts:

```
Sub SumTotals()

lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("b" & lastrow + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("sheet1").Range("b2:b" & lastrow))
Range("a" & lastrow + 1) = Cells(1, 1)
Range("a1:b" & lastrow).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

The issue I am running into is that the code sums both company A and company B and the ends up

> Company A 5,625.07

What I am trying to accomplish is

> Company A 2,053.73
>
> Company B 3,571.34

When I get these reports there is generally 100 + companies so if I can speed up the process it would be very beneficially.

I suspect the first line of code is the problem

```
lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

As this is placing the end at cell `B8` instead of `B3`.  I am trying to figure out how to sum the first column of numbers until the first blank row, and then carry on to the numbers below and carry out the same process.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

ideal end result
[Ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DFJS.jpg)

Comment: Is there always a blank row between two companies?

Comment: Yes there is, the format is the same each time the report is generated.  All the data is in columns A & B and there is a blank row between each company.

Comment: Maybe use `SUMIF` rather than `SUM` if it's dependent on the company name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
    r(r.Count + 1).Value = Application.Sum(r)
    r(r.Count + 1).Offset(, -1).Value = r(1).Offset(, -1).Value
    r.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked very well!  thank you.  I am wondering (and I will work on this) how would I incorporate replicating the company name beside the final sum as well as deleting individual amounts that make up the sum?  Lines 3-5 in what I have written.  Thanks again, this gives me a lot to work with.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, the amended code above should do what you want.

Comment: yes, it gets to the issue I have been hung up on, but I'm still trying to achieve the final format of Company A 2053.73 and below that Company B 3571.34 with the numbers that went into those sums deleted.  I'm trying to merge your suggestion with my initial post but I am getting a range error

Comment: I mocked up a small example and that's what I got. What is not working for you? I'm assuming you want the company name and the sum in different cells.

Comment: Ok, I missed the update you did.  This works perfectly!!  Thank you so much.  It really helps seeing the correct version of what I was trying to do.

Comment: OK, so does it work now?  The results I got tallied with your screenshot.

Comment: Yes, working very well.  Thanks for your help.  You solved in minutes what I've been fighting with all morning and into the afternoon.

Comment: If you can understand why it works - and I can explain it - then next time you probably won't need us.

Comment: That would be ideal, but I don't know if it will be reality.  I suspected I would need a loop, but searching on line (youtube and general searches) my initial bit seemed the way to go.  I've not encounter .Areas before, that is completely new to me.

Comment: Each area is a contiguous block of data i.e.bounded by a space so that way it picks up the values of each company. It loops through each area and in the cell after the last cell of the area (the blank cell at the end) it puts the sum of the cells in the area, then copies the company name from the cell to the left of the first cell in the area, and finally it deletes each row in the area.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.  I tried the discussion/chat link as I would like to ask more questions but it is not opening?  I don't want to get banned so I'll end with this.

Comment: Ha, don't worry don't think you'll be banned. You're ahead of me anyway, I can't see the link. Usually a message appears once the discussion reaches a certain length.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this non VBA approach. Enter this formula `=IF(A1<>"",SUM(OFFSET(B1,0,0,MIN(IF(B1:B80="",ROW(B1:B80))))),"")` in cell `C1` to sum all values before blank row. drag formula to the bottom of your values. Since it is an array formula, you must enter it using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. You can then filter out blank values in column `A` to get your result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I will consider it.  I am trying to go further with the VBA side of things, but this looks feasible.